# How to change the afterSubTpl tagfield color in extJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I am using tagfield and displaying sometext below the tagfield. For that I am using `afterBodyEl: 'This is description'` Text is coming as black in color. Also the it is occupying the  tagfield area. Can anybody tell me how to change the text color. Any css can apply then how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple You can use this.

`afterSubTpl: '<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Your Text</span>',`